# C: getchar() destroys pointer

Tags: c, linked-list, getchar

```
typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;
struct LinkedList {
    LinkedList* next;
    char* head;
    char current;
};

LinkedList makeList()
{
    char* headPointer = calloc(60, sizeof(char));
    LinkedList temp = { 0xCCCCCCCC, headPointer, 0 };
    return temp;
}
int addToList(LinkedList* lstPointer, char toAdd) {
    if (lstPointer->head == NULL || lstPointer->head == 0xCCCCCCCC)
        return -1;
    if (lstPointer->current + 1 < 60) { /* enough space in the list to add */
        *(lstPointer-> head + lstPointer -> current) = toAdd;
        lstPointer->current = lstPointer->current + 1;
    }
    else /* not enough space, will create new node in the list */
    {
        if (lstPointer->next == 0xCCCCCCCC) {
            LinkedList nextNode = makeList();
            lstPointer->next = &nextNode;
        }
        
        return addToList(lstPointer->next, toAdd);
    }
    /*Added succsessfully*/
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    char chr;
    LinkedList lst = makeList();
    while ((chr = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (addToList(&lst, chr) == -1)
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i am trying to use linked list but after i fill the first, i create a new one and able to add an item to it. on the second item the next list pointer get destroyed by getchar(). i have no idea why or how is it related.

Comment: `lstPointer->next = &nextNode;` That's Undefined Behaviour because `nextNode` is a local variable. Local variables become invalid when the function exits and using such references afer that is UB.

Comment: BTW: using `0xCCCCCCCC` as a special pointer value is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `makelist` you need to allocate a new list, but then instead of returning it, you copy it into a local variable, leaking the memory that you just allocated.  Instead, return a pointer:

```
LinkedList *makeList()  // Note *
{
    LinkedList *temp = calloc(1, sizeof(LinkedList));
    temp->head = calloc(60, sizeof(char));
    temp->next = 0;
    temp->current = toAdd;
    return temp;    // Note temp is a pointer
}
```

In `addToList` you don't need the `nextNode` variable:

```
lstPointer->next = makelist();
```